# ListView Selection Rectangle in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How can I temporarily disable listview selection rectangle, so when someone clicks the listview and holds the button down & moves the mouse, the rectangle is not shown? And how do I enable it again after that? (VB.NET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the enabled property to false, then back to true again to enable the selections. It will display a a gray background when it is disabled.